# spot color print - how to indicate white

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, print-design, cmyk

I prefer to work with the web, so it's been forever since I've worked with a printer. Just received this message back regarding a doc utilizing white ink. How can I accomplish this in Adobe Illustrator? (The doc is already assigned CMYK.)

> What we need are print ready PDFs with the white ink designated as a
>   Spot Color titled "White."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double-click the "White" swatch in the Swatches Panel inside Illustrator.

Change the top dropdown menu to Spot Color:

[image: swatch options]

Click Okay.

Now select all the white elements in your piece and ensure they are using that swatch for the stroke/fill color.

**Note, simply adjusting the Swatch options isn't enough.** You'll have to manually reset all the objects using White to this swatch.